# NSXMLParser expected result is repeated over and over and adding 1 item at time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

Im new to Objective-C and XML please help me with my simple problem.

I have this XML file.[XML sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZMlC.png)

I want to put the parsed XML to NSDictionary. The problem is that the result is like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FZ4p.png)

The result is repeated over and over and adding 1 item at a time.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *)attributeDict {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CATALOG"]) {
    self.cd = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CD"]){
    self.content = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}

self.ElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (id key in attributeDict) {
    NSLog(@"attribute %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:key]);
}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {    

self.ElementValue = [self.ElementValue stringByAppendingString:string];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if (![elementName isEqualToString:@"CD"]){
    [self.content setObject:self.ElementValue forKey:elementName];
} else {
    [self.cd addObject:self.content];
}

NSLog(@"%@",self.cd);

}
```

Comment: can you share the xml file or that url?

Comment: Why don't you use breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems correct, I guess you're confused with the multiple `NSLog` output. Which is normal since `didEndElement` will be called for each element. You should see your final array in `parserDidEndDocument` method.

Please implement `parserDidEndDocument` delegate method and see that your array has right number of elements

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
  NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n");
  NSLog(@"- - - - - - - - - - - - - Parsing Finished - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
  NSLog(@"%@",self.cd);
}
```

---

Also there is little problem in your code corrected as below

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  [self.ElementValue appendString:string];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CD"]) {
    [self.cd addObject:self.content];
  }
  else if (![elementName isEqualToString:@"CATALOG"]) {
    [self.content setObject:self.ElementValue forKey:elementName];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! Much appreciated.